# AlloyUI: react to node - click event in Diagram Builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, yui, alloy-ui

i want to react in a different way to the event when a user clicks on a node in the diagram builder.

I know how to create custom nodes (I found the discussion here on stackoverflow) but I do not know how to overwrite the code that gets called when a user clicks the node.

I tried it with extending the "custom node" example :

```
 Y.DiagramNodeCustom = Y.Component.create({
    NAME: 'diagram-node',

    ATTRS: {
        type: {
            value: 'custom'
        },
    },
    on: {
  render: function(event) {                        alert('render node');                      
     },
      click: function(event) {                        alert('click node');                    
     },
      select: function(event) {                        alert('select node');                      
     }

    },

    EXTENDS: Y.DiagramNodeTask
});
```

... but no luck

Who can tell me how I can replace the click event listener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the function on the library

```
_onNodeClick: function(event) {
    var instance = this;
    //get the object
    var diagramNode = A.Widget.getByNode(event.currentTarget);
    //mark as selected
    instance.select(diagramNode);
    //open edit pannel
    instance._onNodeEdit(event);

    event.stopPropagation();
},
```

Comment: You´re right ! Using "prototype" I could overwrite the method and hook into the process. Thanks a lot :)